# How to test RTK Query with react testing library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, rtk-query

I'm trying to work with RTK Query, but can't find a good example of how to write unit tests with react testing library for a component that uses requests with RTK Query.

For example, we have a component that gets a list of something from server. How do mock data for requests? I found a solution to use `mswjs` for mocking API for tests.

But even with it, I have a problem: I need to add `await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 1000));` before I'll check that something from the collection exists.
Maybe, somebody knows how to test components with RTK Query?

Comment: small updates - await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 1000));  don't needed because of waitForElementToBeRemoved to await remove loader. But maybe somebody has examples of unit testing components with RTK Query

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can take a look at [the tests of RTK Query itself](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/64a30d83384d77bcbc59231fa32aa2f1acd67020/packages/toolkit/src/query/tests/buildHooks.test.tsx#L95-L114).

Some things:

- use `msw` to mock an api
- wrap your component in a real Redux store with your api (`storeRef.wrapper` in the example)
- use something to wait for UI changes like

```
      await waitFor(() =>
        expect(screen.getByTestId('isFetching').textContent).toBe('false')
      )
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative I have found is mocking the rtk query hooks themselves. Then you can set anything you want for the data object.

```js
jest.mock('pathToHook', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: () => () => { data: 'whatever you want' },
}))
```

Comment: but what pathToHook would look like if we're talking about a default hook generated by RTK?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do something like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import { useGetData } from './api'; // RTK Query API

import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

jest.mock('./useGetData');

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    useGetData.mockClear();
  });

  it('should render data after API request', async () => {
    const mockData = {
      id: 1,
      name: 'John Doe',
      email: 'johndoe@example.com'
    };
    useGetData.mockReturnValueOnce({
      data: mockData,
      isLoading: false,
      isSuccess: true,
      isError: false,
      error: null,
    });

    render(<MyComponent />);

    // Check that loading state is not displayed
    expect(screen.queryByText('Loading...')).toBeNull();

    // Check that data is displayed correctly
    expect(screen.getByText('Name: John Doe')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText('Email: johndoe@example.com')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

In this example, we are testing that `MyComponent` correctly displays data after a successful `useGetData` hook call. We simulate the `useGetData` hook by mocking it using `jest.mock` and setting up a mock return value using `useGetData.mockReturnValueOnce`. Then, we render the component and verify that the loading state is not displayed and that the data is correctly displayed using expect statements. It's worth noting that we don't need to wait for an API request to complete, as `useGetData` already returns the data we wish to test.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. You saved a lot of my time.

Comment: ```const hookMocked = jest.fn();
jest.mock('path-to-the-module-you-want-to-mock', () => ({
  hookThatYouWantToMock: () => hookMocked(),
}));
```
Then you can use mockClear() inside beforeEach() and mockReturnValueOnce() inside the tests :)

Comment: What about mocking a mutation or a lazy query how could you do it ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use "jest-fetch-mock" (npm i -D jest-fetch-mock)

After set it in your jest setup file (jest.setup.ts)

```
import fetchMock from 'jest-fetch-mock'

fetchMock.enableMocks()
```

And use in your test file by this way:

```
import fetch from 'jest-fetch-mock'

it('render hints if data exists', async () => {
    fetch.mockResponse(JSON.stringify(['test']))
    
    const { getByText, getByPlaceholderText, store } = renderWithProviders(<SearchBar />)
})
```

fetch.mockResponse(JSON.stringify(['test'])) // will return ['test'] in every request result (even in rtk query query hook), you can pass your own data you need.